# Smartmontools ouput anlysys

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, smartmontools

I am trying understand the  smartmontools, when I executed the command "smartctl -a /dev/sda"
It shows the part of output with heading"SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1"
under which a column named "remaining" in % is tells that when error found in hard disk 90% of check is remaining part of output command is below.

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      9343         4196472
```

I want to understand that wheather the test is stopped after 10% or continues to check full hard disk, If hard disk check stops when It find error, Is there any way to force to continue full scan of hard disk please any one help me out thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your disk had read errors and should be considered as dead.  Replace it.

Comment: Thanks for help, But I am trying to know that, will test get stop when it find first error or tests hard disk completely.

Comment: The test is listed as "completed", as there is no point in testing the disk further. I repeat: It's dead, replace it. Don't waste time on it.